Circle Topology problem -> Flat Shading artifacts

I made the half circle in the middle using the spin tool, but now the vertex count doesn't match up with the sorounding edges, to what I think lead to bad topology and the shading artifact thing.
When finished, I want to use the model for 3D Print, btw.

(I'm a total Blender beginner and don't speak English natively, just so you won't be confused when I made a mistake or something)

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186849/why-are-my-objects-shadows-so-janky/  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269746/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-shading-and-modeling/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126838/help-with-curved-groove-on-curved-surface/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/how-to-cut-a-rounded-hole-in-a-sphere
